# C++ / Bazel: How to include angle <> bracket system headers?

Tags: c++, bazel

Problem: I'm struggling to build against an external dependency included with angle brackets.

Background: I have a header file which includes the Eigen library as so:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

This is installed locally on the system as an external dependency. For various reasons, modifying how dependencies are installed isn't a realistic option currently.

So I need a consistent encapsulate external dependencies as Bazel targets. Currently I'm working on a header only target that looks like this:

```
cc_library(
   name = "my_library",
   hdrs = [ "some/local/header.h"],
   textual_hdrs = ["@system_deps//:eigen3"],
   deps = ["@system_deps//:eigen3"],
)
```

This is based on my understanding that (1) non-.h files need to be in textual_hdrs and (2) the fact that it definitely doesn't see it when it's not part of deps. But I admit I'm grasping in the dark here.

This of course points at my WORKSPACE:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "system_deps".
  path = "/usr/include/eigen3",
  build_file_content = """
     cc_library(
       name="eigen3",
       textual_hrds = glob["Eigen/*"]),
       visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
     )
  """,
  )
```

Result: error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found with  blah blah

(This occurs when my header file is include somewhere else.)

Interestingly it *does* somehow find Eigen/Dense, as it complains (correctly) it can't find another file included. Not sure if

So: what's the *right* way to do this? I've read other similar questions but haven't quite grasped how to encapsulate these external dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Does the attribute [`cc_binary.includes`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.includes) help?

Comment: Update, managed to get it to find it using this: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/182

Now it complains about angle brackets being used. I've tried "includes" in every configuration I could think of, but no. Wants me to drop those angle brackets!

What does work:

1) Using quotes instead of the angle brackets. (As requested.) This would eventually be fine, but it prevent any sort of parallel build system during migration. 

2) Using --copt="-I/usr/include/eigen3/" .... My reading says this is equivalent to using includes, but somehow not? 

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use strip_include_prefix and/or include_prefix, bazel will add -I flag instead of -isystem. it's an ugly inconsistency, I agree. But I still consider it better than copts (especially since copts is not transitive, if a target depends on your target, they'd have to add copts manually again).

Comment: If I could upvote @hlopko more than once I would! Saved me after 4 hours of head scratching! :)