# Fixing includes with Bazel

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, bazel

I am trying to fix includes with a local copy of `openssl` with bazel 5.0 on Mac using the `clang` compiler.

The file structure is as follows.

```
WORKSPACE 
external 
  openssl
    libcrypto.a
    libssl.a
    include
      openssl
        conf.h
        .
        .
        .
```

Whenever I build `openssl` or anything dependent on it like https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost. I get errors like the following.

```
In file included from external/com_github_nelhage_rules_boost/src/build_asio_ssl.cpp:1:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/impl/src.hpp:22:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:24:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:23:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp:19:
external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:23:10: fatal error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found
#include <openssl/conf.h>
```

or

```
In file included from contrib/epee/src/network_throttle-detail.cpp:58:
In file included from ./contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.h:49:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:18:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/context.hpp:23:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp:19:
In file included from external/boost/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_types.hpp:23:
external/openssl/include/openssl/conf.h:19:11: fatal error: 'openssl/macros.h' file not found
# include <openssl/macros.h>
```

I am curious what other people have done to fix this sort of thing. I have tried adding `includes = ["external/openssl/include/openssl"]` and `includes = ["include/openssl"]` to the `cc_library` rule for `openssl`. I have also tried `strip_include_prefix = "include/openssl"` from [C++ / Bazel: How to include angle <> bracket system headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427219/c-bazel-how-to-include-angle-bracket-system-headers).

Comment: This is clearly incorrect `["external/openssl/include/openssl"]` because the directory `openssl` is being mentioned twice, once here, and once in the `#include`. It should be `["external/openssl/include"]`

Comment: The directory structure is top_level > external > openssl > include > openssl. Even if I try `"include/openssl"` or `"external/openssl/include` it fails to find the path. This is what it puts as a compiler option `external/openssl/whatever/path/is/in/includes`

Comment: Well I don't know anything about Bazel, but I do know that duplicating the first directory in the `#include` as the last directory in the compiler include path option is a common error. The compiler option should be (for g++) `-Iexternal/openssl/include`

Comment: THAT WORKED. It needed to be `includes = ["include"]`. Thank you so much!